# Permission denied for ANY task at root's crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, cron

I have this (and just this) at root crontab

```
    * * * * *  /bin/true
```

tail /var/log/cron.log lists

```
    Sep 13 19:53:01 host CRON[9881]: Permission denied
    Sep 13 19:54:01 host CRON[9882]: Permission denied
    Sep 13 19:55:01 host CRON[9890]: Permission denied
    Sep 13 19:56:02 host CRON[9891]: Permission denied
```

Before anyone asks:

```
    # ls -l /bin/true
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27280 Mar  2  2017 /bin/true
```

No matter what task I command, I always get "permission denied" and nothing is executed, obviously.

Any comments?

Comment: And what about `ls -l /usr/bin/crontab` ? Does it have `setgid` permission set?

Comment: Yes it does:
# ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root messagebus 36080 Apr  5  2016 /usr/bin/crontab

Comment: I apologise for the question, but what does `host` mean in your log messages? Is it your real hostname?
`Sep 13 19:53:01 host CRON[9881]: Permission denied`.

Comment: Nope! It is not the real machine hostname This was changed to "protect the innocent"!

Comment: And what happens if you add `* * * * *  root /bin/true` to `/etc/crontab`? Please find `root` before the command name.

Comment: Does not make any sense since it *IS* a root crontab, but I did it anyway. Same result: permission denied.